# Firefox font size too small for some websites

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I have some problems related to the font size displayed in Firefox for websites. It is too small and I can't figure out how to change it. So far I have tried :

- Unity Tweak Tool, but I have found nothing related to web browser
- Firefox settings, but it doesn't work for all the websites I have tried
- Ubuntu settings, but it does not affect websites.

I have just moved from a Windows environment, and everything was well displayed before. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands work in most web browsers:

Ctrl + '+': Increases the font size
Ctrl + '-': Decreases the font size

You can also use the mouse:
Ctrl + Mouse Wheel Scroll Up: Increases the font size
Ctrl + Mouse Wheel Scroll Down: Decreases the font size

Comment: Thank for you answer. Actually I was thinking about a more permanent solution. If it is that simple to zoom in, I thought there was a simple way to set it by default ?

Comment: When you change the font size the new size is supposed to be set as the new default. Isn't this happening?

Comment: It does, thank you for that. Is there any way to define the default zoom for a generic webpage ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last question. When you "zoom in" and exit the browser, and it saves your zoom state as the new default, this will already be used for any given page. Thus, for any 'generic webpage', as you put it, the new (bigger) default zoom will already be defined.

Comment: And if this solved your problem don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough. For example, when I have a 120% zoom on a website A, when I go to website B I still have a 100% zoom. However when I come back to website A, I get back my 120% as you said. I hope it's clearer ?

Comment: And by the way thank you very much for your patience :)

Comment: Strange. It should save the zoom for all websites, not only website A. 
This may not be what you're asking, but have you tried installing Chrome (https://www.google.com/chrome/)? 
Maybe there's something broken in your firefox installation and font sizes will work fine with another browser

Comment: I just tried with chromium, and the default settings are more readable than for firefox. I think I will just use your shortcuts, thank you !